# Intregrating OnlieMeeting MS (Graph api) inside my Laravel app for users Calls

Tags: php, laravel, api, microsoft-graph-api

I want to integrate Ms online meeting graph API in my application for my clients (users) using Laravel (PHP) to facilitate the calls and online chat between them, for this moment I just learned how to use This API and test it with Postman. My question is if there are some resources on how to develop app and integrate Graph API with it(online meeting) on Laravel?

Thanks

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow :) Your question is very broad. What have you looked for already? And what have you tried?

Comment: Hello, I want to integrate Ms online Meeting in My App (Built with Laravel PHP) to let users (organizations) calls each other's and organized meeting !, I tried understanding how API Graph work using Postman (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/graph/use-postman) i need some resource about DEV and integrate API (ceate meeting) in My App (Laravel)!!!

Comment: Does something like this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48280296/1343140 It would be better to post code that is not working. Providing links to how to's is not really the purpose of Stack Overflow